# ZoomableDraweeView is released and reset when the overview button is pressed

Tags: android, fresco

I have an activity with a `com.facebook.samples.zoomable.ZoomableDraweeView`. When the phone's [overview button](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32697/what-is-the-offical-name-of-the-third-on-screen-button) is pressed, the `onSaveInstanceState()` method is called, and I am storing `DefaultZoomableController.transform` value in case the view needs to be re-created. However, if I immediately return to my app, `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` is not called and I do not have a transform value to restore, but the `ZoomableDraweeView` is already reset to its initial state. Apparently `onCreate()` is not called if the view does not need to be re-created.

Then, `ZoomableDraweeView` should not be going back to its initial state. I see the `transform` value is reset at:

```
at com.facebook.samples.zoomable.DefaultZoomableController.reset(DefaultZoomableController.java:93)
at com.facebook.samples.zoomable.AbstractAnimatedZoomableController.reset(AbstractAnimatedZoomableController.java:44)
at com.facebook.samples.zoomable.DefaultZoomableController.setEnabled(DefaultZoomableController.java:108)
at com.facebook.samples.zoomable.ZoomableDraweeView.onRelease(ZoomableDraweeView.java:368)
at com.facebook.samples.zoomable.ZoomableDraweeView.access$100(ZoomableDraweeView.java:43)
at com.facebook.samples.zoomable.ZoomableDraweeView$1.onRelease(ZoomableDraweeView.java:69)
at com.facebook.drawee.controller.AbstractDraweeController.releaseFetch(AbstractDraweeController.java:193)
at com.facebook.drawee.controller.AbstractDraweeController.release(AbstractDraweeController.java:169)
at com.facebook.drawee.components.DeferredReleaser$1.run(DeferredReleaser.java:65)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-1)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

How can I suppress calls to `ZoomableDraweeView.onRelease()` and/or `DefaultZoomableController.reset()`?

Answer (score 0):

Although most of the state is saved and restored automatically by fresco, it seems the `ZoomableController.transform: Matrix` is not managed automatically. I resolved this issue by making a copy of the Matrix during `Activity.onPause()` and restoring it during `Activity.onResume()`.

For [example](https://github.com/kiewic/cdmx-metro-y-metrobus/commit/e1d12d9a56c7c7e1b44a0d89575384797cbe0324#diff-b3cd9eb5b2197a7b5610c15b59418c7d):

```
class MainActivity {
    private var transform: Matrix = Matrix()

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        defaultZoomableController.transform = transform
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        transform = Matrix(defaultZoomableController.transform)
        super.onPause()
    }
}
```